# Running "apply" command on a very large data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, parallel-processing, tibble

I have a tibble in R that has dimension of `15,000,000 x 140`. Size-wise it's about 6 gb.

I want to check if any of columns 11-40 for a given row start in a specific list. I want to get out a vector of 1 & 0's that is then 15,000,000 long.

I can do this using the following:

```
subResult <- apply(rawData[,11:40], c(1,2), function(x){substring(x,1,3) %in% c("295", "296", "297", "298", "299")})

result <- apply(subResult, 1, sum)
```

Problem is that this is way too slow -- it would take over 1 day to do just for the first line.

Is there any way to do this faster -- perhaps directly through dplyr or data.table?

Thank you!

Here's a sampling of the data trimmed to just columns 11-40.

```
!> head(rawData)
 # A tibble: 6 x 30                                                                                                                                                                               
   X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9    X10   X11   X12   X13
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 39402 39451 3fv3i 19593 fk20 14p4  59304  329fj2 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 2 39422 f203ff vmio2  vo2493  19149 59833 13404 394034 43920  349304   59302 1934 34834
 3 3432f32 fe493  43943 H2344 53049  V602  3124  K148 K13  NA    NA    NA    NA
 # ... with 17 more variables: X14 <chr>, X15 <chr>, X16 <chr>, X17 <chr>,                                                                                                                         
 #   X18 <chr>, X19 <chr>, X20 <chr>, X21 <chr>, X22 <chr>, X23 <chr>,                                                                                                                             
 #   X24 <chr>, X25 <chr>, X26 <chr>, X27 <chr>, X28 <chr>, X29 <chr>, X30 <chr>
```

Comment: Use `rowSums(subResult)` to make it fast or with `tidyverse` `subResult %>% reduce('+')`

Comment: @akrun, that might make the second part faster. What about the first part -- that's what takes the most time now. When I check the substring.

Comment: sorry,  it is not clear from which package you are using `pbapply`.  Would also be better if you can provide a small reproducible example

Comment: I've changed it to just apply now. The package name is actually pbapply -- it shows you a progress bar for apply commands but works similarly. This way you can time how long your apply commands take. - Also, sorry, the data is confidential, but it could just be a random tibble with character columns.

Comment: Not tested without a reproducible example. Try `rawData %>% select(11:40) %>% mutate_all(funs(substring(.,1,3) %in% c("295", "296", "297", "298", "299")))  %>% reduce('+') %>% mutate(rawData, newcol = .)`

Comment: Regarding why it is so slow, you are using margin as (1, 2) which will go through each element instead of row or column

Comment: A faster option could be `library(data.table);setDT(rawData)[, newCol := Reduce('+', lapply(.SD, function(x) substring(x, 1, 3) %chin% c("295", "296", "297", "298", "299"))), 
         .SDcols = 11:40]`

Comment: To solve this kind of problem it is often useful to benchmark different solutions on a subset of the data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the description, this can be done either with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
rawData %>%
   select(11:40) %>% #select the columns
   #convert to logical columns
   mutate_all(funs(substring(.,1,3) %in% c("295", "296", "297", "298", "299"))) %>% 
   reduce('+') %>% #get the rowwise sum
   mutate(rawData, newcol = .) # assign a new column to the original data
```

---

Or with `data.table` by converting the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(rawData)`), specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols`, loop through the columns, convert it to logical by using the OP's condition, `Reduce` by taking the `sum` of each row and assign (`:=`) to 'newcol'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(rawData)[, newCol := Reduce('+', lapply(.SD, function(x) 
      substring(x, 1, 3) %chin% c("295", "296", "297", "298", "299"))), 
     .SDcols = 11:40]
```

Answer (score 3):

My comments:

- apply converts your data to a matrix
- a data frame is above all a list, not a matrix
- `substring()` is a vectorized function (`%in%` too)

So, I would do:

```
sapply(rawData[11:40], function(var) {
  substring(var, 1, 3) %in% c("295", "296", "297", "298", "299")
})
```

and then use `rowSums()` instead of `apply(subResult, 1, sum)`.

Comment: @this was very helpful -- especially rowSums(). I gave akrun the answer as he answered first but rowSums() is fantastic. If I could give two answers I would put both of yours down. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `Rcpp` package.

Here is a simple C++ program which takes two string vectors, and checks if 3 characters of elements in first are equal to the second one. So it will output logical matrix of size length(first vector) x length(second vector).

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
LogicalMatrix IndicatorMatrix(std::vector<std::string> target, std::vector<std::string> tocheck) {

  int nrows = target.size();
  int ncols = tocheck.size();

  LogicalMatrix ind(nrows, ncols);

  for(int r=0; r<nrows; r++) {
    for(int c=0; c<ncols; c++) {

      bool found = target[r].substr(0,3) == tocheck[c];
      ind(r,c) = found;

    }
  }

  return ind;

}
```

After that you can source this program into R and use your `IndicatorMatrix` function as if it would be a R function object.

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("C:/Users/Desktop/indicatorMatrix.cpp")

rep("123456", 15000000) -> x
df <- data.frame(x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
y <- c("123", "124", "345", "231", "675", "344", "222")


t1 <- Sys.time()
out <- lapply(1:length(df), function(col) {

  res <- IndicatorMatrix(unlist(df[,col]), y)
  res

})
t2 <- Sys.time()
t2-t1
```

Program searched for 8 3-character strings in 8 column data frame with 15 milions of rows in about 100 seconds. So this could be right direction for you.