# Call "multi file C++ code with external libraries referenced" in R

Tags: c++, r

I have written a code in C++ which uses boost library and also uses multiple files. I am trying to execute the function in R.

Here is my C++ function prototype:

```
extern "C" double function1(double rho, double mu, double limit);
```

Here is my R function:

```
dyn.load('path_to_dll\\x64\\Debug\\project.dll') 
.Call("function1", as.double(1.0), mu = as.double(1.0/20.0), limit = as.double(3413.85))
```

When I am calling the function, it gives me following error:

```
Error in .Call("function1", as.double(1), mu = as.double(1/20),  : 
  C symbol name "function1" not in load table
```

I have followed [this](http://forums.approximatrix.com/viewtopic.php?id=494)
But no luck. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please do not post images of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this a multi-file C++ project, you should package the code as an R package. It is actually quite easy to do using Rcpp, see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50358745/8416610). The [Rcpp-package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-package.pdf) vignette contains further information. In addition, an easy way to make use of `boost` is via the [BH](https://cran.r-project.org/package=BH) package. There are many example packages for using Rcpp + BH on CRAN which you can study, e.g. my own [dqrng](https://cran.r-project.org/package=dqrng). Some more details can also be found in the [R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/) book and of course in the official documentation [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html).

The crucial thing for using the BH package is `LinkingTo: BH` in the `DESCRIPTION` file. This ensures that `-I<path_to_BH_package>/include` is part of the compiler flags. In order to use header files that you place in `inst/include`, you should add `PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I../inst/include` to `src/Makevars`.

Comment: And several [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org) posts illustrate it.

Comment: I did followed your suggestion and went through your package dqrng. You are using boost library but there is no header file there. Is it that you are using BH package when you are building or installing the package? I am using this command R CMD INSTALL --library="C:\Users\user1\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\BH" project2_1.0.tar.gz

Comment: Also, I added inst/include folder in the package and copied boost library files there. But getting this error:
Euler.h:6:53: fatal error: boost/math/special_functions/binomial.hpp: No such file or directory

Comment: @user1584253 Please see the update. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I am using Windows.  Should I create file Makevars in src folder and add PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I../inst/include in it?

Comment: @user1584253 The compiler flags generated from `LinkingTo` work also on Windows. I have removed the explicit path which might be confusing.

Comment: @RalfStubner I linked BH file using 'LinkingTo' attribute and package is successfully installed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `Rcpp` instead of `.Call`.

Add this headers and comment to your .cpp function file:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
```

And now in R:

```
 install.packages("Rcpp")
 library(Rcpp)
 sourceCpp('path to your .cpp program')
```

The function `EulerInversions` should become visible in the environment and you can call it now as any other R function

Comment: Here is my example which I posted in other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49645059/running-apply-command-on-a-very-large-data-frame/49646644#49646644

Comment: Where can I find Rcpp.h file ? to reference in cpp file

Comment: Also, SourceCpp gives error  "Error 1 occurred building shared library." Is it because .cpp file contains reference to other files?

Comment: In R\library\Rcpp\include folder path.

Comment: To be honest I only used Rcpp for very limited and simple C++ programs, which didin't use any of external C++ libraries. But here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570526/how-to-build-a-r-package-which-use-rcpp-with-external-c-libraries the author of the Rcpp library is explaining how to use external C++ libraries. Sorry that I can't help at this stage.

Comment: Note that it is `sourceCpp()` with a lower-case `s`.